# AKS error - Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, azure-aks

I have docker desktop and kubectl installed , I am trying to connect to cluster from my local pc and getting above error
here is my kubeconfig file

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: ****
  name: AKS-CLUSTER
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: AKS-CLUSTER
    user: clusterUser_D-AKS_AKS-CLUSTER
  name: AKS-CLUSTER
current-context: AKS-CLUSTER
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: clusterUser_D-AKS_AKS-CLUSTER
  user:
    client-certificate-data: ****
    client-key-data: ****
    token: ****
```

Comment: Are you behind a corporate firewall or using a VPN?

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeBond yes I am using VPN , I get same error with or without VPN

Answer (score 1):

One reason for this is the AKS cluster certificate getting rotated. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/certificate-rotation.

As outlined there, run:

```
az aks get-credentials -g <RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME> -n <CLUSTER_NAME> --overwrite-existing
```

and see if it gives you an output like:

```
Merged "<CLUSTER_NAME>" as current context in /home/<USER>/.kube/config
```

Comment: If you need to log in first then execute `az login --scope https://management.core.windows.net//.default` before `az aks ...` command.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this issue when trying to deploy an app to **Azure Kubernetes Service** using **Azure DevOps**

I was getting the error below:

> Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "ca")

**Here's how I solved**

The issue was due to expired credentials of the **Service Connections** that the Project was using.

All I had to do was to:

- Go to **Azure DevOps** > **Project Settings** > **Service Connections**.
- Renew the **Service Connections** credentials or create a new one and reference it in the project.

After this, when I ran the deployment pipeline again, everything went fine.

Comment: Does this solution apply to the self-hosted agent?

Comment: Yes it should apply as well

Comment: how do you "Renew" the service connections?

Comment: @FabianVal You can renew in the Azure AD (Microsoft Entra) service principals - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/monitoring-health/recommendation-renew-expiring-service-principal-credential